# MYSQL Replace Like doesn't Work

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-like

I have a problem with a query:

```
UPDATE 
    `MY_COLOR` 
SET 
    `Color` = REPLACE(`Color`, ' ', '') 
WHERE 
    `Color` LIKE ('L %')
```

The same query without "WHERE `Color` LIKE ('L %')" work.

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `MY_COLOR` WHERE `Color` LIKE ( 'L %' )' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a syntax error in `LIKE` clause.
Use 
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE field1 like '%abc%';`
So in your case, it will be
`UPDATE MY_COLOR SET Color = REPLACE(Color, ' ', '') WHERE Color LIKE 'L %';`